# TikZ: Plot a sine function with a complicated argument

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot the function $\sin (1/x)$ using tikZ. The plot works out OK for positive values of $x$, but not for negative values of $x$.

The code for one of my attempts follows:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-6.5:6.5,samples=4000,scale=1,>=latex]
\tikzset{bgrid/.style={help lines,color=blue!10,very thin}}
\draw[bgrid] (-6.5,-1.5) grid (6.5,1.5);
\draw[<->, color=black] (-6.5,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {\(x\)};
\draw[<->, color=black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {\(y\)};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6}
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {\(\xtext\)};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-1,1}
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {\(\ytext\)} ;
\draw[thick,color=black,domain=-6.5:-0.05,samples=2000] plot (\x,{-1*sin(1/\x r)});
\draw[thick,color=black,domain=0.05:6.5,samples=2000] plot (\x,{sin(1/\x r)});
\filldraw (0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw (4.7,1.5) node {\(g(x) = \sin \left ( \frac{1}{x}\right )\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: You could invert positive values, since `sin(1/x)` is an odd function: `\draw[thick,color=black,domain=0.05:6.5,samples=2000] plot (-\x,{-sin(1/\x r)});`

Comment: I think the issue is your lack of parentheses: `\draw[thick,color=black,domain=-6:-.05,samples=2000] plot (\x,{sin((1/\x)r)});` works for me.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio : This works; thanks very much!

Comment: @DJP : This also works; thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of plotting `\x` vs. `sin(1/\x r)` it's probably better to plot `1/\x` vs. `sin(\x r)` which will samples the regions close to zero much more finely.  You still cannot pass through zero because 1/0 is ill-defined and close to zero you run into numerical problems.  To this end, just split the domain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \begin{axis}[
    width=12cm,
    axis equal image,
    xmin=-6.5, xmax=6.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=major,
    no markers,
    ]
    \addplot+[domain=-1/6:-1/0.02,samples=300,smooth] ({1/(\x)},{sin(\x r)});
    %\draw ({-0.02},{sin(-1/0.02 r)}) -- ({0.02},{sin(1/0.02 r)});
    \addplot+[domain=1/0.02:1/6,samples=300,smooth] plot ({1/(\x)},{sin(\x r)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here with markers to show the improved sampling:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks very much, Henri. This works for me and produces much better quality.

Answer (score 3):

As an attempt to get better accuracy with Asymptote. The code in page 33 of [this tutorial](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) does not work on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ due to `thin()` option (I do not know why!). I use `linewidth(.3pt)` instead. The sample number `n=10^4` seems to be biggest number in this case.

[image]

```
unitsize(1.5cm);
import math;
import graph;
real a=.005, b=3;
pen bg=.2yellow+.8white;
pen  lw=linewidth(.3pt);
add(shift(-b,-2)*grid(6,4,gray+linewidth(.1pt)));
pair F(real x) {
return (x, sin(1/x));
}
draw(graph(F, a, b, n=10^4),lw+red);
draw(graph(F, -a,-b, n=10^4),lw+blue);

draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint,align=SW),(0,-1.5)--(0,1.5), Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,align=SW),(-b,0)--(b,0), Arrow(TeXHead));
clip(box((-3,-1.5),(3,1.5)));
dot("1",(1,0),S);dot("-1",(-1,0),S);

label("$y=\sin\frac{1}{x}$",(-2,1),Fill(bg));
shipout(bbox(5mm,Fill(bg)));
```

Comment: Thanks, BM. I have used Asymptote in the past, and it is nice to have a secondary solution as a future option.

Comment: @FoMaP you are welcome! as Menke said above, using `pair F(real t) {
return (t, sin(t));}` give nicer figure